# Back to in HTML on Ubuntu not working

Tags: html, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I'm working with HTML and i'm, trying to back two folders in HTML on ubuntu.
In windows if i use:

```
    ../../
```

It works, but in ubuntu it doesn't work. I have the same structure of folders in windows and ubunto, and in windows is working, but in ubunto it doesn't work.

How could i do this on ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget the `cd ../../`?

If it doesn't work try `\` instead of `/`

**EDIT**

Something like this:

```
<a href="/home/aa/Documents/docs/internet.html">Link here</a>
```

Comment: I have: <a href="../../Sesion09-loginAPP/index.php" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">

Comment: try it without the file

Comment: My folder is not in home, is back